# matplotlib.plot in embedded IPython immediately shows plot with no chance for modifying the returned axes

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

Embed IPython in a script and run:

```py
from IPython import embed

# code ...
embed()

%matplotlib
#^ With or without; same result

fig = plt.figure()
```

Can't do anything with `fig` at this point.

It's already `show`n and the window is displayed,
even though I never called `show`.

```py
plt.show() # does absolutely nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally import matplotlib in IPython this way:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax, fig = plt.subplots()
plt.plot([[1,1], [2,2]])
plt.show()
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks! (Edited the question to add missing context.) I'm embedding IPython REPL within a running script. `%matplotlib inline` doesn't work then. Just `%matplotlib` chooses the best of what is allowed in this case (Qt5Agg), as I understand it.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Good clarification. :)